# Enumerating ancestors in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I've been playing with some genealogical files in XML lately and wanted to create a transform that would list, for each person, the person's name, the count of ancestors, and the list of ancestors.  Here's what I came up with, but I'd like to see if there's a better way to do this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/people">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="person"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- for each person, print the name and ancestor count -->
<xsl:template match="person">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="count-kin"/>
    <xsl:text>): </xsl:text>
    <!-- now name all of the ancestors -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="name-kin"/>
    <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<!-- recursively name the ancestors -->
<xsl:template match="parent" mode="name-kin">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name,' ')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="myname" select="@name"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/people/person[@name=$myname]" mode="name-kin"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- recursively name the ancestors -->
<xsl:template match="person" mode="name-kin">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="parent" mode="name-kin"/>
</xsl:template>


<!-- recursively count the number of ancestors -->
<xsl:template match="parent" mode="count-kin">
    <xsl:variable name="myname" select="@name"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ancestor-count">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/people/person[@name=$myname]" mode="count-kin"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$ancestor-count"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- recursively count the number of ancestors -->
<xsl:template match="person" mode="count-kin">
    <xsl:choose>
    <!-- only count ancestors if there are any -->
    <xsl:when test="count(parent)">
        <xsl:variable name="ancestor-count">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="parent" mode="count-kin"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="number($ancestor-count)+count(parent)"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <!-- no parents -->
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's a sample input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<people>
<person name="adam"/>
<person name="eve"/>
<person name="cain">
    <parent name="adam"/>
    <parent name="eve"/>
</person>
<person name="henoch">
    <parent name="cain"/>
</person>
<person name="gladys"/>
<person name="frank">
    <parent name="henoch"/>
</person>
<person name="jose">
    <parent name="gladys"/>
    <parent name="frank"/>
</person>
</people>
```

Here's sample output from `xsltproc` on Linux:

```
adam(0): 
eve(0): 
cain(2): adam eve 
henoch(3): cain adam eve 
gladys(0): 
frank(4): henoch cain adam eve 
jose(6): gladys frank henoch cain adam eve
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fun question!

Usually when I find myself doing something like this: `select="/people/person[@name=$myname]"`, I'll use an [xsl:key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#key) instead.

You could use that key to collect all of the `parent`s based on the parent `person`'s `@name` in a variable.

If you could treat that variable as a node-set (either XSLT 2.0+ or [EXSLT's node-set() function](http://exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html)) getting the count of ancestors would simply be a matter of counting the number of items in the node-set (`count()`).

Another option, which feels a little hacky in my opinion, is to output a separator along with the ancestor name.

To get the ancestor count you can remove all characters other than the separator character (nested `translate()`) and then count the number of separators (`string-length()`).

You'd also need to replace all of the separators with a space when you finally output the ancestor names (another `translate()` call).

Example...

**XML Input**

```xml
<people>
    <person name="adam"/>
    <person name="eve"/>
    <person name="cain">
        <parent name="adam"/>
        <parent name="eve"/>
    </person>
    <person name="henoch">
        <parent name="cain"/>
    </person>
    <person name="gladys"/>
    <person name="frank">
        <parent name="henoch"/>
    </person>
    <person name="jose">
        <parent name="gladys"/>
        <parent name="frank"/>
    </person>
</people>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="parent" match="parent" use="../@name"/>

  <xsl:template match="person">
    <xsl:variable name="ancestors">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('parent',@name)"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="ancestor_count" 
      select="string-length(translate($ancestors,translate($ancestors,'|',''),''))"/>      
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name,'(',$ancestor_count,'): ',translate($ancestors,'|',' '))"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="parent">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name,'|')"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('parent',@name)"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
adam(0): 
eve(0): 
cain(2): adam eve 
henoch(3): cain adam eve 
gladys(0): 
frank(4): henoch cain adam eve 
jose(6): gladys frank henoch cain adam eve
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MEdvhm